# Threads on client server [java]

Tags: java, multithreading, client, server

I'm trying to do multi client server. I already setup server with multithreading. And my question is How Can I join(run) for example 20 clients at one time? I need to use threads aswell? I'm thinking about creating constructor with my client to set connection and get random name and then create loop which go through 20 of them and set them up?
Here is the code:
//Server

```
package com.multi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    public static final int PORT = 4445;


    public void startServer(){
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Server is waiting for connetions...");

            while (true) {
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                new ServerThread(socket).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Server().startServer();
    }

}
```

//server multithreading

```
package com.multi;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    Socket socket;
    String message = null;

    ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println("Client: " + message);
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

//client

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Client extends JFrame{

    private String[] names = { "Sara", "Jessica", "Tom", "Emanuel", "Joshua",
            "Kristin", "Kirito", "Goku", "Bulma" };
    private JTextField chatWindow;

    public void clientJoin() {
        for (String name : names) {

            try {
                chatWindow = new JTextField();
                add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
                setSize(300, 150);
                setVisible(true);
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4445);
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(
                        socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.println(name);
                while (true) {
                    String readerInput = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    printWriter.println(name + ": " + readerInput);
                    chatWindow.setText(name);
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new Client().clientJoin();
                }
            };
            new Thread(r).start();            
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to run 20 clients at once now? What is your question??

Comment: I don't know my concept is correct. It will force server to make 20 threads?

Comment: OK, so Can I run them 20 times in a loop and this will work fine right?

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand what you mean by run them 20 times in a loop. You start the server once, then clients connect (like 30 or 50 , doesn't matter) and then the clients type messages which the server displays.

Comment: The serversocket has a queue of 50 so you should be able to connect 20 at once

Comment: umm I have problem once again.. Could you  check my client class again i edited it. Why it just display first name from my array ?

Comment: I see that you are creating 3 objects of Client, and in every object you are trying to make multiple connection attempts. But the it stops at the while (true) loop. So thats why always and only the first name will appear.

Comment: thank you! That was the case indeed.

Comment: I posted the solution I got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Client extends JFrame{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static String[] names = new String[]{ "Sara", "Jessica", "Tom", "Emanuel", "Joshua",
            "Kristin", "Kirito", "Goku", "Bulma" };
    private JTextField chatWindow;
    private static int c = 0;

    public void clientJoin(String name) {


            try {
                chatWindow = new JTextField();
                add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
                setSize(300, 150);
                setVisible(true);
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(
                        socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.println(name);

                System.out.println(name);
                while (true) {
                    String readerInput = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    printWriter.println(name + ": " + readerInput);
                    chatWindow.setText(name);
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (c < names.length-1) {
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new Client().clientJoin(names[c]);
                }
            };
            new Thread(r).start();
            System.out.println("ges here");
            c++;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test concurrent access, then yes, you need to start 20 client threads. Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startAClient();
        }
    };
    new Thread(r).start();            
}
```